# updating mongo in python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a very basic question on updating a mongo collection.

Suppose I have a mongo document like this:

```
{"Object_id:.....,"product_id":1234, "color":0}
{"Object_id:.....,"product_id":1234, "color":1} # note the same product_id
{"Object_id:.....,"product_id":12345, "color":0}
```

Now what i want is:

if product_id == 1234 and color == 1:
     # modify that document to color = 2

after update

```
{"Object_id:.....,"product_id":1234, "color":0}
{"Object_id:.....,"product_id":1234, "color":2} # note the same product_id
{"Object_id:.....,"product_id":12345, "color":0}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is clearly a simple update() operation. Is this homework? Clearly a -1 for zero motivation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To literally do what you want it would be:

```
db.foo.update({"product_id" : 1234, "color" : 1}, {$set : {"color" : 2}})
```

If you had multiple occurrences of product_id == 1234 and color == 1 and you wanted to update them all if found, then it is:

```
db.foo.update({"product_id" : 1234, "color" : 1}, {$set : {"color" : 2}}, false, true)
```